# determine the mass of ice that melts during the impact

Tags: energy, mass-energy, self-energy

During a storm, a mass $m = 2 g$ hailstone falls to the ground. Its speed just before coming to ground is $v = 18 m / s$. its speed just after is zero. Assume that the hailstone is pure ice, the initial temperature $θ_1 = 0 ° C$. The latent heat of melting of ice in the processing conditions is $Lƒ kJ.kg-1 = 330$.

1) Determine the variation of mechanical energy of the hailstones during impact on the ground.

2) Assuming all the lost mechanical energy is transferred to the hailstone determine the mass of ice that melts during the impact.

We have :

$1/2mv_f^2 -1/2mv_i^2 = 0- 1/2 ( 0.001) ( 18) ^2 =-0,162 joul= -Q$

So $Q=0,324$

So we have :

$Q=Lf(m_m)$

So

$m_m=Q/Lf=0,324/330=0,9 g$

It's simple ! But my question is , assuming that the temperature of the hailstone is $-20$ what is the mass of ice melts ?

Comment: Watch out! You are mixing kJ and J, kg and g I think. Convert to a single uniform set of units before doing any calculations. Starting at -20C, you first need to heat the ice to 0 C before you can think about melting any of it. So you need the heat capacity of ice.

Answer (score 0):

The question you ask is very similar to the question that you already answered! I'll go ahead and step you through it.

Before we do anything, we should see if the ice even gets to $0^\circ \text{ C}$! If it doesn't, then none of it will melt. To do so, let's examine how much kinetic energy can be converted to heat:

$$Q = \frac{1}{2}m\Delta(v^2) = \frac{1}{2}(0.002 \text{ kg})(0^2 - (18 \text{ m/s})^2) = -0.324 \text{ J}.$$

So, we have $0.324 \text{ J}$ to work with. Can that raise the temperature of the hail stone to $0^\circ \text{ C}$? Let's find out!

The (mass) specific heat of ice is $c = 2.11 \text{ J/gK}$. So, using conservation of energy again, we calculate the temperature change of the ice if we use the $-0.324 \text {J}$ to heat up the ice instead of leaving the system:

$$0.324\text{ J} = mc\Delta T = (2\text{ g})(2.11\text{ J/gK})\Delta T = 4.22 \Delta T \text{ J}.$$

Solving, we get $\Delta T = 0.077 \text{ K}$. That is, the final temperature of the ice is just barely above its initial temperature: $T_f = -19.923^\circ \text{ C}$. That is, none of it gets to the melting temperature, so none of it melts!